# Захохотать: шутке или над шуткой? Радоваться чему-то и смеяться над чем-то

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

**"...сказал он и захохотал..."**
Дальше написал: "...собственной немудреной шутке", - но это показалось как-то криво.

*Как тут **правильно** сказать: "захохотал **над... шуткой**" или "захохотал... **шутке**"?*

И вдогонку еще один вопрос: *почему радуются **чему-то**, а смеются **над чем-то?***
Вроде бы, похожие понятия, а предлоги - разные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ПРАВИЛЬНО: "...сказал он и захохотал над собственной немудреной шуткой"

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Радость – чувство,  направленное на объект, поэтому используется предлог ПО. Управление сильное. В словаре указывается: чему и с придат. дополнит.

Смеяться, хохотать  - здесь объект необязателен, можно просто смеяться. Но если он присутствует, то  обозначается, скорее, связь  с этим объектом, а не направленность на него.  Управление также сильное:  над кем-чем.  Вариант кому/чему считается устаревшим.